# How can I save an image in code (via pickle, dill, or other bytecode) and save to file if not exist in a file system?

Tags: python-3.x, image, pickle, bytecode, dill

How can I save an image in code (via pickle, dill, or other bytecode) and save to file if not exist in a file system? Python 3.6.5.

There are two photos that I need to be present for the Tkinter app to work. they may or may not be present at all times on the device, so I need to create them as needed. However, I can't figure out how to do it yet that doesn't corrupt the file. Any suggestions?

Current code:

```
with open("0.png", 'rb') as f:
    temp = f.read()
    CogFile = pickle.dumps(temp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    print(FileData)
    pickle.dump(FileData, open("1.png", 'wb'), pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open("0.gif", 'rb') as F:
    temp = F.read()
    CogFile = pickle.dumps(temp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    print(FileData)
    pickle.dump(FileData, open("1.gif", 'wb'), pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: `png` and `gif` have their own on-disk format and its not python pickle. Why not just `shutil.copy('0.png','1.png')`?

Comment: Is there a way to get the byte data and save it in code? The target machine may not have the file(s) available. I'm creating another file to test Functionality.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways. You could do a one-time encode of the default files and then copy/paste into your module source. Or, you could just keep the files with your project and assuming that you've got a `setup.py` to install, keep them with the program.

Comment: How do you do a "one-time encode of the default files and then copy/paste into your module source"?

Comment: Unless your entire program has to be a single `.py` file, there's really no reason not to consider `0.png` as part of your program, which sits in the development directory/repo as part of your "source", and gets installed somewhere accessible at install time as part of your "binary", while just leaving it as a PNG file the whole time. You're overcomplicating things here—changing it into a pickle file leaves you with the exact same problem you already had (now you just need to consider that pickle file as part of your source and binary), plus a new one (you have to convert it back to PNG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed the images in a python file. To do that, the default image bits will need to be in a non-binary format that fits syntactically into the .py file. Here is an encoder file that you can run once and then paste the results into a .py file as a variable. It does a base64 encode to convert the binary file into acscii and wraps that all in a python `bytes` object.

```
import sys
import base64

try:
    var = sys.argv[1]
    fn = sys.argv[2]
    with open(fn, 'rb') as fp:
        print(var, '= b"""\\')
        for line in base64.encodebytes(fp.read()).split(b'\n'):
            if line:
                print(line.decode('ascii'))
        print('"""')
except (IndexError, OSError):
    print("usage: pyencode.py variable_name file_to_encode")
```

As an example

```
$ python3 pyencoder.py dft_png stackoverlow.png 
dft_png = b"""\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==
"""
```

Once pasted into a program the decoding would be

```
import base64

dft_png = b"""\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==
"""

with open('1.png', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(base64.decodebytes(dft_png))
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! If this is all you need, accept the answer so people can quickly tell that you have the solution.